# IOS App save data to server

Tags: ios, database, save, server

Please forgive the broadness of the question, I am looking for advise.

I have saved user entered data on the device, I am looking for advise on how can I combine data from everyone who's using the app (stored in many different devices) to a database where only certain people can view.

Is using a server the best way to achieve this? After saving it locally, I would upload them to a server?  If that's the case, how can I do that (tutorial URL would be nice), what server do most developers use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Facebook's free service, [Parse.com](https://parse.com). It has great features for databases and is very easy to integrate into iOS apps.

The Objective-C for Parse is very basic:

```
PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
gameScore[@"score"] = @1337;
gameScore[@"playerName"] = @"Sean Plott";
gameScore[@"cheatMode"] = @NO;
[gameScore saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
  if (succeeded) {
    // The object has been saved.
  } else {
    // There was a problem, check error.description
  }
}];
```

This code would create an object called `GameScore` with the fields `score`, `playerName`, and `cheatMode` and would store it in your database.

I would recommend reading the [Parse Documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide) before you make a decision though.

Comment: This service will be closed in 2017.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely broad question, so I will give you a bit of a broad answer :D

There are several types of servers (though you are really talking about a database) that one could use - it could be written in Java, PHP, SQL, Node, etc...

It really depends on the data you are trying to save, and your experience in using any backed/network libraries.

If you are just getting started in this, I would recommend using a Software-as-Service as your initial backend, rather that either a) writing your own by finding a NodeJS tutorial etc or b) using something a bit more complicated like Amazon Web Services or Heroku.

I happen to like [Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/), as it has good documentation, robust features, cross-platform SDKs and a nice visual data editor, but you could also use StackMob, Azure, and many more...